# Change CSS3 Transform Value?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

i have a css3 class with transform

```
.temp{
    transform: rotate(45deg) scale(0.8,1.2) skew(60deg,-30deg);
}
```

then how can i get and change rotate frome .temp? only rotate,not transform.
thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your transform styles are declared in CSS, you have to bring out the computed style from the element to modify it:

```
var temp = document.querySelector('.temp')
var styles = window.getComputedStyle(temp, null).getPropertyValue('transform');
```

The problem here is that you will get the matrix (in chrome at least), something like:

```
matrix(1.0555833735058735, 0.07578747639260253, 0.13126775968941418, 1.828324034537128, 0, 0)
```

So unless you want to modify the matrix parameters, I suggest you set and modify the styles via javascript instead of CSS:

```
var transform = 'rotate(45deg) scale(0.8,1.2) skew(60deg,-30deg)';
temp.style.transform = transform;
```

Now you can do a string replace:

```
temp.style.transform = transform.replace(/45deg/,'90deg');
```

Demo (using webkit prefix for chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/hZAvk/

```js
var temp = document.querySelector('div')
var transform = 'rotate(45deg) scale(0.8,1.2) skew(60deg,-30deg)';

temp.style.WebkitTransform = transform;

setTimeout(function() {
    temp.style.WebkitTransform = transform.replace(/45deg/,'90deg');
},1000);
```

```css
.temp{
    height:100px;background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="temp"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that, you'll just have to replace the whole value. 
Maybe use string manipulation to modify it

```
var temp = document.getElementsByClassName('temp')[0]; //this is for the first one    
temp.style.transform = temp.style.transform.replace('rotate(45deg)', 'rotate(75deg)');
```

Edit: David is right, there is no tranform property in `style`. His solution is better, but you might find [this](http://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/) useful.

Comment: There is no transform property in the style declaration, you need to get the computed style.

Comment: You're right. There isn't. I'm trying $('.temp').css('transform') but the computed value returned isn't easy to understand